# Convert html form to wordpress theme form

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

I have contact page and I have form to send masseges. How can I add function to get masseges and have them in my wp dashbord; Also without plugin and just php codes or wordpress tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few steps in doing this

1. Getting the data in php
   Exactly like you do in php. with $_POST (you probably used $_POST), and I'd also recomment to have a variable to verify if form has been submitted like "formSubmitted=1" and have something like `if(isset($_POST['formSubmitted']) && $_POST['formSubmitted'] == '1') { ...`
2. Adding the data in database.
   Exactly how you add the data in database you you can find [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)
3. List item
   You can use [add_menu_page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) for this and list your data with $wpdb in your new page.